# SwiftUI Firestore data doesn't showing on the first load

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

i connected my app wirh Firestore. Everything works fine exept for my data does not show first time when i launch the app. When i switch between tabs, the data shows. It's accting like [Place] array is appending slowly after my app shows. How to force to show data on the first load? here is code:

```
class FirebaseManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var places = [Place]()

    init() {
        fetchData()
    }


    func fetchData(){
        Firestore.firestore().clearPersistence()

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("places").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

     self.places.removeAll()

            for i in (snap?.documentChanges)!{
                let name = i.document.data()["name"] as! String
                let type = i.document.data()["type"] as! String
                let desc = i.document.data()["desc"] as! String
                let image = i.document.data()["image"] as! String
                let loc = i.document.data()["loc"] as! String
                let contact = i.document.data()["contact"] as! String
                let fol = i.document.data()["followers"] as! String


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.places.append(Place(id: fol, name: name, type: type, description: desc, image: image, location: loc, contact: contact))
                    print(name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct topView : View {


    @ObservedObject var firebaseMan = FirebaseManager()


    var body : some View{

        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15){

            Text("Clubs & Places")
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .regular))


            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {

                HStack(spacing: 15){

                    ForEach(0 ..< firebaseMan.places.count) {i in
                        Image(self.firebaseMan.places[i].image)
```

I tried with .onAppear{... on view, but that doesn't help too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! This code is ok, but in SwiftUI ScrollView has a problem that it's not refreshing observasble object! After ScrollView always check if (your @Published var) =! nil! I hope Apple will resolve this problem soon, in next update.

Comment: Hey - I'm running into this same issue and I heavily use scroll views. do you have any code samples to show how you fixed this issue? 

Basically whenever I sign out and sign in with a new user, I either see the previous user's data OR if I close the app and reopen it and then login, I see no data until I relaunch the app. can't believe it's a scrollview bug!